# (tinymce) How to create new custom inline tagging in new dropdown

Tags: jquery, html, tags, tinymce-4

**Hi, I have problem how to create a custom dropdown menu like formats in tiny mce**

[image]

**So, I want to create a custom dropdown menu and there have several of custom inline tagging inside.
For example :**

```
<question></question>
<answer></answer>
<hint></hint>
```

**I was reffering to references in tiny mce about 2 example :**

1- Custom formats
http://codepen.io/tinymce/pen/QjzgRW

2- Custom dropdown
http://codepen.io/tinymce/pen/JYwJVr

**But, I'm still stuck to modified them and create custom inline tagging in new dropdown, help me please :)**

Answer (score 1):

Hi try to add this code in your one of your plugins code :

```
var items = [];
editor.addMenuItem('questionitem', {
    text: 'question',
    cmd : function(){
        editor.insertContent('your custom tag');
    }
});

items.push(editor.menuItems['questionitem']);



editor.addButton('customdropdown', function () {
    return {
        type: 'listbox',
        text: 'Formats',
        tooltip: 'Formats',
        values: items,
    };
});
```

Don't forgot to add customdropdown btn in your toolbar.

Comment: Thanks,I will try later because I got one of solution here 
http://jsfiddle.net/380w7y69/21/